# Python. Вывод бинарной кучи

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется массив,который с помощью heapq преобразовывается в двоичную min-кучу.
Как его вывести с помощью цикла слоями?

Просто позднее пригодится реализовать добавление/удаление и такой способ как раз кстати.

Что-то вроде дерева:

_________0

_____1________2

__3____4___5_____6

7___8___9

Без "_" естественно.

Или,например, без отступов:

0

1 2

3 4 5 6

7 8 9

Понимаю,что применяется метод format в варианте с деревовидным выводом, но не могу понять как все вместе это реализовать.

Часть кода:

```
import random
import heapq


 r = int(input())
 data = [random.randint(0,50) for x in range(10)]

  if r == 1:
     print(data)
     heapq.heapify(data)
     print(data)
```

Comment: Куча - полное двоичное дерево. Так что по количеству элементов можно узнать количество уровней и количество пробелов между элементами на каждом уровне.

Comment: Это я понимаю, но мне не приходит в голову,как все это провернуть в цикле,не прибегая к прямому обозначению элементов каждого уровня,чтобы оно потом еще и менялось в зависимости от добавления/удаления эл-тов.
В общем,не могу скомпоновать все в один единственный цикл.

Comment: Сделайте два цикла - один по уровням, второй по элементам уровня

Comment: Не могли бы вы простенький пример составить,пожалуйста?
Общую суть я понял,но как-то оно у меня не выходит.